# Unable to 'ionic cordova build' No scripts found for hook "after_compile" and "after_build"

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

Unable to get `ionic cordova build android` to work.

INFO:

- ubuntu 20..,
- node 10,  ionic 5,
- local angular 8,
- gradle 5,
- android sdk 28, 30.
- all vars are exported...As far as I can tell

***FIRST:***  After npm install and global ionic, cordova and angular install I run the command `ionic cordova build android`.I get this error in the output :

```
...
      ember-cli:testing cli: command.validateAndRun +1ms
    The specified command run is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
            
            ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 1.
```

***SECOND :***     running `ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android` resolves without errors, even though it "exited with exit code 1" when running 'ionic cordova build android'

***THIRD :***  after running `ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android` i ran `ionic cordova build android` and got this result with no apk in build folder:

```
    ...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 23s
42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
Command finished with error code 0: /home/art/Documents/obc/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/art/Documents/obc/platforms/android/build.gradle
Built the following apk(s): 
        /home/art/Documents/obc/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
No scripts found for hook "after_build".
art@pop-os:~/Documents/obc$
```

**Am I missing some steps before running `ionic cordova build android`?**

**Are there ways to force it to run the script to completion?**

**Do I need to add the "after_compile", "after_build" script to the package.json file ?**

Comment: Without your `package.json` it is difficult to support you with the failing command `ionic cordova build android`. Please add it to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks could be defined in project's `config.XML` using `<hook>` elements, for example:

```xml
<hook type="before_build" src="scripts/appBeforeBuild.bat" />
<hook type="before_build" src="scripts/appBeforeBuild.js" />
<hook type="before_plugin_install" src="scripts/appBeforePluginInstall.js" />

<platform name="android">
    <hook type="before_build" src="scripts/android/appAndroidBeforeBuild.bat" />
    <hook type="before_build" src="scripts/android/appAndroidBeforeBuild.js" />
    <hook type="before_plugin_install" src="scripts/android/appAndroidBeforePluginInstall.js" />
    ...
</platform>
```

The path to the apk file is written after the successful build. Locate in your log:

```
Built the following apk(s): /home/art/Documents/obc/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```